# ¿Como hacer para que cuando haga click en un Item de un listview en Android studio me abra una nueva activity

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

¿Como hacer para que cuando haga click en un `Item` de un `ListView` en **Android Studio** me abra una nueva `activity.xml`?

Es es el código que tengo:

```
package com.example.juan.pruebaprueba;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listviewmodelo;
    String[] listviewlista = new String[] {
            "Elemento 100",
            "Elemento 200",
            "Elemento 300",
            "Elemento 400",
            "Elemento 500",
            "Elemento 600"
    };
    List<String> convertString;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        listviewmodelo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        convertString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(listviewlista));

        arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, convertString);

        listviewmodelo.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente configura un [OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)  a tu `ListView`, dentro puedes definir el abrir la `Activity`:

```
...
...

     listviewmodelo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     convertString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(listviewlista));
     arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, convertString);
     listviewmodelo.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

     //Configura Listener.
     listviewmodelo.setOnItemClickListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        // Abre una nueva Activity:
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), nuevaActivity.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);

                        }
                    }
            );
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Jorgesys, soy nuevo en estas aplicaciones; tienes correo electrónico para enviarte mi archivo para que lo revises; Para configurar el Listener tengo que declarar alguna variable en el archivo java?

Answer (score -2):

Sobre lo que indicas, Como se puede hacer para que al seleccionar un ítem se redireccione a diferentes Activities?
Actualmente solo puedo mostrar las posiciones en las que se encuentran:

```
listviewmodelo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "posicion ="+i+" opcion =? ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Si tratas de realizar una pregunta te recomiendo no lo realices en esta, realiza una nueva para que otros desarrolladores la vean!.